# C++ Program- Not sure if, I am providing the right solution

Tags: c++

I have a test tomorrow, as a "guide" for the test there is the question below, I have wrote up my solution, but not sure if I am doing what the question is asking? Thanks for the help!

> Write an interactive C++ program that inputs a name from the user in the format of:

> ```
> last, first middle
> ```
>
> The program then should output the
> name in the format of:

> ```
> first middle last
> ```
>
> The program
> will have to use a string operations to remove the comma from the end
> of the  last name.

Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 


using namespace std;

const string FIRST = "Firstname";
const string LAST = "Middlename";
const string  MIDDLE = "Lastname";

int main()
{
string firstLast;
string lastFirst;

firstLast = LAST + ", " + FIRST + " " + MIDDLE;
cout << "Name in first-last format is " << firstLast << endl;

lastFirst = FIRST + " " + MIDDLE + " " + LAST;
cout << " Name is last-First format is " << lastFirst << endl;



system("PAUSE");
return 0;


 }
```

Does this solution complete what the question is asking? Some people were having trouble in my class and It seemed that this solution was too easy? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: It says to input the name from the user. You have it hardcoded into the program.

Comment: And you are not "using string operations to remove the comma".

Comment: Not only does the input need to come from the user (presumably as a single string), there needs to be a comma after the last name.

Comment: It's asking you to get the name from the user as a single string, then parse that into three separate strings so that you can then piece them together in the specified format.

Comment: So, basically make a data file and use indata outdata?

Comment: @user: No, "from the user" means at the command prompt (e.g. via `cin`). If it had to do with file input, the question would have so specified.

Comment: @user2026243, It means input as in the user typing it into the program using the keyboard. This would entail the use of something like `std::cin` or `std::getline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this solution complete what the question is asking?

No.

Examining the test question in parts...

> Write an interactive C++ program

Your program is not interactive.  There is no interaction with the user.  It runs to completion immediately.

> that inputs a name from the user in the format of: `last, first middle`

Your program doesn't do that.  It should allow the user to type `last, first middle` or presumably any name in that format.

> The program then should output the name in the
>   format of:
>
> `first middle last`

Your program doesn't do that.

Or, more accurately, it outputs 18 words instead of 3, but 3 of them **are** the 3 words that the program was supposed to output.

> The program will have to use a string operations to remove the comma from the end of the last name.

Your program doesn't do that.  There is no code that removes a comma from anywhere.

I recommend:

- Reading about `std::cin`
- Reading about `std::string` member functions
- Coffee, if possible.  You are not prepared for this test.